# ROR Devise: allowing username or email logins: undefined local variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, devise

I've been following the tutorial on the Devise github page here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address

I'm in the second part of the tutorial where we allow users to recover their password using either their username or email and there's a large block of code that the tutorial says to copy into the User model.  This is the line that throws an error:

```
def self.find_record(login)
  where(attributes).where(["username = :value OR email = :value", { :value => login }]).first
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `attributes' for #<Class:0xa70e1a8>):

app/models/user.rb:63:in `find_record'
app/models/user.rb:44:in `find_recoverable_or_initialize_with_errors'
app/models/user.rb:30:in `send_reset_password_instructions'
```

Anyone know why this error is showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing in any attributes, and there's no 'attributes' class method, so `where(attributes)` doesn't work. It doesn't look like you need to either. Change your method to:

```
def self.find_record(login)
  where(["username = :value OR email = :value", { :value => login }]).first
end
```

For what it's worth, I don't see how it would have worked in the tutorial either.